# Why is the max heap much smaller than the value I set in Xmx (with -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseParallelOldGC)

Tags: java, solr, garbage-collecting, jvm

I am running a **SolrCloud** on k8s with the following setting:

Heap params:

```
-server -Xms280m -Xmx312m
```

Other params:

```
-XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyOutputInterval=1 -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=300 -XX:GCTimeRatio=19 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128m -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=90 -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled
```

And the max heap shown on the admin page is only **277.5m**, which is **34.5m** less than Xmx

[image]

And if I change the heap params to

```
-server -Xms312m -Xmx312m
```

Then the max heap is around 300m, which is much closer to the Xmx

My questions is that:

- Why is there such a big difference in the first setting?
- Why does the difference get smaller when I set Xms = Xmx
- Would JVM still honor my Xmx setting? (Would my application still be allowed to grow to 312m?)

**More observations...**

I've tried this with another memory setting:

```
-server -Xms296m -Xmx360m
```

and the max heap shown on Solr's admin UI is **320m**

After doing some math, it seems that the max heap is always around 90% of the Xmx I set.

```
  312 * 0.9 = 280.8 (just 3.3m more than 277.5m)
  360 * 0.9 = 324  (just 4m more than 320m)
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is some details.

`-Xmx` = maximum java heap

`-Xms` = initial and minimum java heap

The `-Xmx` option and `-Xms` option in combination are used to limit the Java heap size. The Java heap can never grow larger than `-Xmx`. Also, the `-Xms` value can be used as “minimum heap size” to set a fixed heap size by setting `-Xms` = `-Xmx`.

However `-Xmx` does not limit the total amount of memory that the JVM can use.

Here is my answer inline

> Why is there such a big difference in the first setting?

It's because of difference between initial memory and max memory heap.

> Why does the difference get smaller when I set Xms = Xmx

For production system I would suggest use same, reason is you will get kick start and less gc most of the time, again it's depend on workload and system profiling and nature of application.

> Would JVM still honor my Xmx setting? (Would my application still be
>   allowed to grow to 312m?)

Answer is yes, but don't confuse with Xmx and JVM. Heap will grow when application need more resources.

## EDIT 1:

Heap having these 3 parts:

1. Eden
2. Survivor
3. Tenured
4. Reserved

Per your snapshot it shows 3 parts till 195.13MB till 209.50MB till 277.50MB and rest if reserved.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi sorry .... I am still a bit confused... in the first setting, I set -Xmx312m, why is the max heap shown on Solr's admin page only 277.5m?

Comment: So, you assigned -Xms280m which mean process start with 280mb if required it will consume more and reachout to Xms. 280mb/312mb doesn't assigned complete jvm hold some memory for it's own internal purpose.

Comment: Hi! do you mean reach out to Xmx?

Comment: say you started your program and -Xms is 280m it's start with 280m memory but used heapsize will be > 280 since jvm reserve some memory, if gradually it reached to 312m also it's will use > 312mb memory due to reservation for memory management.

Comment: So... can I say 277.5m is the initial heap bound set by Xms (Xmx is the max upper bound)? But this way what is the number 209.5m shown in the picture?

Comment: Edited my answer with more details.

Comment: thanks! do you mean the following?
, 195.13MB : Eden
, 195.13MB ~ 209.50MB Survivor
, 209.50MB ~ 277.50MB Tenured

But I don't think I ever saw Eden area this big...

Have I mistaken something?

Comment: Enable gc logging you will get each details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106036/discussion-between-john-the-traveler-and-asktyagi).